# Use pandas_udf with spark 2.2

Tags: pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

Is there anyway to use [pandas_udf](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python-pandas.html) in pyspark 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are creating a function then a pandas_udf from that given function.
If you want to use it as a pyspark udf, all you have to do is creating a pyspark udf from that function.
With the given example on databricks documentation :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def multiply_func(a, b):
    return a * b

#the return type depends on your values, so it can be DoubleType()
multiply_func_udf = udf(lambda x,y: multiply_func(x,y), IntegerType())

#then you can call like
spark_df.withColumn("multiplied_values",multiply_func_udf(col("x"),col("y"))
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to use apache arrow in spark 2.2 which is supported by default in spark 2.3